# Lodash 3.10: How to get two parameters of an object?

Tags: javascript, frontend, lodash

I have several parameters inside the object, some of these parameters are other lists that have other characteristics.

Ex:

```
"company": {
      "name": "blablacar",
      "array": {
             "param1": "blabla",
             "param2": "blabla"
       }
}
```

With the lodash _.pluck has how do I capture this data ...
but in my case, I'm building a new object, in which I would like the parameter name of the enterprise object to be part of the array parameter. In the end, array would have 3 parameters.

How would this algorithm look? Is there something ready in doc lodash 3.10?

Result:

```
"array": {
    name,
    param1,
    param2
}
```

Comment: what you are asking is not clear. Update your question and put what the end result should be like

Comment: Please show desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the `name, param1 and param2` in a new object you can simply do:

```js
var company = { "name": "blablacar", "array": { "param1": "blabla", "param2": "blabla" } }

const result = {array: {name: company.name, ...company.array}}
console.log(result)
```

Without even using lodash and only ES6. It is not very clear the desired output from the input etc but hopefully that is what you mean and I understood you correctly.